# Php stdclass object returned to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, object

I have only recently started usign ajax and i have run into a slight problem.
The code is as follows:

1. Input form -> Value to AJAX.
2. AJAX sends the form value to a php function that sends the request to a server.
3. The server returns a stdClass object with the query results.
4. PHP sends the results as responseText back to AJAX to be displayed on the webapp.

**The problem:**

stdClass Object is a PHP object that i now am stuck with, it is not possible to change the output format of the server in question.

I have tried all the possible array/object/variable - combinations i can think of and also tried to json_encode the object. However this solutions only returns a long set of strings, as does a var_dump on the object. I might be horrible wrong, having absolutely no experience with json.

I need some guidance on how to pass the object to AJAX in a format i can output with JavaScript.

**AJAX Code:**

```
function checkSerial(serial) {

        console.log(serial);

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          $responseText=xmlhttp.responseText;
          console.log($responseText);
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","../module/getdevice.php?serial="+serial, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**Outputted stdClass. Sorry about the censored values.**

```
object(stdClass)#5 (15) {
  ["censored"]=>
  string(12) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(29) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(1) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(8) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(7) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(0) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(56) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(47) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(47) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(30) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(14) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(0) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(0) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
  string(0) "censored"
  ["censored"]=>
```

Hopefully this post is not a duplicate, i have tried my best to actively search for a solution.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the solution: `json_encode()` on the server side.

To convert your long string in javascript to an object you can use, you need to parse it:

```
console.log( JSON.parse($responseText) );
```